# Linear Regression using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, regression

I would like to do a linear regression with an NDVI collection.

Does anyone know how can I do the regression using Google Earth Engine?

Comment: Always check documentation: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_regression

Answer (score 2):

you can use ee.Reducer.linearRegression(numX, numY) API,the details search in GEE document.